# Sidebar implementation: [Routes] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route>

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to implement a SideBar but keep it excluded from the `/login` route.

My code seems to be a mess at the moment, and I'm not quite sure why I'm getting this error at the moment.

This is what I'm trying to do at the moment:

App.js:

```
<Router>
    <div className="App">
        <SideBar
            onCollapse={(inactive) => {
                console.log(inactive);
                setInactive(inactive);
            }}
        />
        <div className={`container ${inactive ? "inactive" : ""}`}>
            {menuItems.map((menu, index) => (
                <>
                    <Route key={menu.name} exact={menu.exact} path={menu.to}>
                        <h1>{menu.name}</h1>
                    </Route>
                    {menu.subMenus && menu.subMenus.length > 0
                        ? menu.subMenus.map((subMenu, i) => (
                            <Route key={subMenu.name} path={subMenu.to}>
                                <h1>{subMenu.name}</h1>
                            </Route>
                        ))
                        : null}
                </>
            ))}
            <Routes>
                <Route exact path="/login" element={<Login />} />
                <Route exact path='/' element={<ProtectedRoutes />}>
                    <Routes>
                        <Route exact path='/main' element={<Main />} />
                    </Routes>
                </Route>
            </Routes>
        </div>
    </div>
</Router>
```

menuItems:

```
export const menuItems = [
    {
        name: "Dashboard",
        exact: true,
        to: "/",
        iconClassName: "bi bi-speedometer2",
    },
    {
        name: "Content",
        exact: true,
        to: `/content`,
        iconClassName: "bi bi-speedometer2",
        subMenus: [
            { name: "Courses", to: "/content/courses" },
            { name: "Videos", to: "/content/videos" },
        ],
    },
    { name: "Design", to: `/design`, iconClassName: "bi bi-vector-pen" },
    {
        name: "Content 2",
        exact: true,
        to: `/content-2`,
        iconClassName: "bi bi-speedometer2",
        subMenus: [
            { name: "Courses", to: "/content-2/courses" },
            { name: "Videos", to: "/content-2/videos" },
        ],
    },
    { name: "Design 2", to: `/design-2`, iconClassName: "bi bi-vector-pen" },
    { name: "Design 3", to: `/design-3`, iconClassName: "bi bi-vector-pen" },
    { name: "Design 4", to: `/design-4`, iconClassName: "bi bi-vector-pen" },
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is here:

```
<Routes>
  <Route exact path="/login" element={<Login />} />
  <Route exact path='/' element={<ProtectedRoutes />}>
    <Routes> // <-- here!!
      <Route exact path='/main' element={<Main />} />
    </Routes>
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

If you are just trying to nest routes then you don't need an additional `Routes` component. The `Routes` component would only be needed if rendering a component rendering descendent routes.

Remove the `Routes`:

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
  <Route element={<ProtectedRoutes />}>
    <Route path='/main' element={<Main />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

If you want to exclude UI components on certain routes then create another layout route component like you did with `ProtectedRoutes`.

Example:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const SideBarLayout = ({ inactive, setInactive }) => (
  <>
    <SideBar
      onCollapse={(inactive) => {
        console.log(inactive);
        setInactive(inactive);
      }}
    />
    <div className={`container ${inactive ? "inactive" : ""}`}>
      {menuItems.map((menu) => (
        <React.Fragment key={menu.name}>
          <Link to={menu.to}>
            <h1>{menu.name}</h1>
          </Link>
          {menu?.subMenus?.map((subMenu) => (
            <Link key={subMenu.name} to={subMenu.to}>
              <h1>{subMenu.name}</h1>
            </Link>
          ))}
        </React.Fragment>
      ))}
    </div>
    <Outlet />
  </>
);
```

...

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
  ... other routes w/o SideBar ...

  <Route element={<SideBarLayout {...{ inactive, setInactive }} />}>
    ... other routes with SideBar ...

    <Route element={<ProtectedRoutes />}>
      <Route path='/main' element={<Main />} />
      ... other protected routes ...
    </Route>
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! after making the suggested changes, I'm now getting a `A <Route> is only ever to be used as the child of <Routes> element, never rendered directly. Please wrap your <Route> in a <Routes>.` for some reason.

Comment: @DanielL It might be the routes you are trying to render from `menuItems`. Where do you want these rendered? Within the `SideBarLayout` layout route? Actually, now that I look at it, rendering `Route` components doesn't make sense here... did you mean to render `Link` components instead?

Comment: I'd like to show them in the sidebar always except on the login

Comment: @DanielL Yes, that is how layout routes work and handle including/excluding UI on specific routes. Is `menuItems` array/object supposed to be menu items that ***link*** to the specific routes?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still a bit confused. how should the sidebar layout look as a whole and how should app.js should look as a whole?

Comment: @DanielL The code in my answer is pretty much it. I'm *assuming* that your `SideBar` component already renders the UI it needs, *as a sidebar*. Is that not the case? What is the purpose of `menuItems` in your code example?

Comment: I just edited the question and added `menuItems` :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246653/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-daniel-l).

Answer (score -1):

Try to wrap your  between Router tags, like this:

```
<Router>
         <Route exact path="/login" element={<Login />} />
                <Route exact path='/' element={<ProtectedRoutes />}>
                    <Routes>
                        <Route exact path='/main' element={<Main />} />
                    </Routes>
                </Route>
      </Router>
```